# Minimum difference with Digits

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers

You have digits from $0$ to $9$, where you have to use every digit only once.

create 2 numbers from the digits so the difference is minimum.

example :  $30568 - 29471 = 1097$

What is the lowest result you can get?

Comment: Problem might be more interesting if you could only use each digit once *across both sides of the equation*.

Comment: Can the differnce be negative?

Comment: *difference, sorry.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Minimal value is

> $50123-49876 = 247$

<sub>*Taking "difference" as the unsigned distance between the numbers, rather than $\ (a-b)\ $, this is the minimal difference possible between two numbers which use all 10 digits exactly once between them.   Verified by brute force search.*</sub>

Comment: Yep...this is it.

Answer (score 3):

2 variables: 50123-49876=247.

3 variables: 5071-4982-63=26

4 variables: 987-654-321-0=12

5 variables: |108-26-47-35-9|=9

6 variables: ?

7 variables: 95-67-8-4-3-2-10=1

8 variables: 45-8-7-9-6-3-2-10=0

9 variables: 41-8-7-9-5-3-6-2-0=0

10 variables: No positive difference.

Comment: You can get 0 with 8 vars by switching the 6 and 7.

Comment: |109-27-48-35-6| =  7

Comment: 3 variables are enough: 5013-4987-26=0

Answer (score 3):

The answers already here give the correct answer but don't really explain why it's right, so it seems like it may be worth explaining a bit.

First of all, obviously the numbers must both be 5 digits long because otherwise, even if we allow 0 as a leading digit, the difference is at least 012345-9876=2469, and as we'll see it's easy to do better than that.

Now, the leading digit of the larger number must (by definition) be bigger than the leading digit of the smaller. Clearly we want it to be just 1 bigger. Then, to minimize the difference, we want the remaining digits of the larger number to be as *small* as possible (i.e., the smallest 4 of the remaining digits, in increasing order) and the remaining digits of the smaller number to be as *large* as possible (i.e., the largest 4 of the remaining digits, in decreasing order).

And now we make the small part as small as possible *and* the large part as large as possible by using digits 0123 for the small part and digits 9876 for the large part; so those two leading digits must be 4 and 5.

This gives us 50123 - 49876 = 247.

Answer (score 0):

Minimum:
0 - 987654321 = -987654321

Comment: There is no negative difference. Difference between 2 numbers is |A-B|. so it always a non negative number.

Answer (score 0):

This puzzle reminds me of the puzzles on https://projecteuler.net/ .

Brute force method yields the same answer as @Rubio in less than 20 seconds:

Answer:

> 50123 - 49876 = 247

Output:

> ```
>     ===================== 5 =====================
>     70143 - 69852 = 291
>     70142 - 69853 = 289
>     70134 - 69852 = 282
>     70132 - 69854 = 278
>     70124 - 69853 = 271
>     70123 - 69854 = 269
>     60134 - 59872 = 262
>     60132 - 59874 = 258
>     60124 - 59873 = 251
>     60123 - 59874 = 249
>     50123 - 49876 = 247
>     ===================== 4 =====================
>     ===================== 3 =====================
>     ===================== 2 =====================
> ```

Here is the code that produced it:

```
import sys, itertools, re

def main(argv):
    digits = "0987654321"
    first_num_len = 10
    #curr_best = pow(10, len(digits)+1)
    curr_best = 300

    for first_num_len in xrange(len(digits)/2, 1, -1):
         print "=====================", first_num_len, "====================="
         #split up the digits in every possible way
         list = map("".join, itertools.permutations(digits, first_num_len))
         second_num_len = len(digits) - first_num_len
         for num_str in list:
            # get the balance of digits
            delta_digits = ''
            for ch in digits:
                if not ch in num_str:
                    delta_digits+=ch
            list2 = map("".join, itertools.permutations(delta_digits))

            for num_str2 in list2:
                diff = abs(int(num_str) - int(num_str2))
                if(diff < curr_best):
                    if(int(num_str2) < int(num_str)):
                        print num_str, '-', num_str2, '=', diff
                    else:
                        print num_str2, '-', num_str, '=', diff
                    curr_best = diff

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Hope that helps.